# parsing and concatinating a json string in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json string like that

```
{
"6ad416d7-551a-41e3-9103-42d0a6a14d95":{
  "0":{
     "value":"KOSHER ONE"
  }
},
"acb022a1-2369-4a20-8b6e-714387b81a6c":{
  "0":{
     "value":"PAREVE"
  }
},
"f4ef2148-270e-4d9d-913d-f1a4ed2a73f0":{
  "0":{
     "value":"Crayon"
  }
}
}
```

And i want to extract and concatinate the following values like that KOSHER ONE+PAREVE+CRAYON.

Can anybody help me to parse this string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an entire [JSON library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

You'd parse the string with [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), then retrieve the values from the resulting object graph.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()` to decode the json data and you can change the values.

Once you updated all the values, use `json_encode()` to change it back to json string

json_encode: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
json_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php